# Discrete Fourrier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I'm learning the DFT (Discrete Fourrier Transform), and came across a mathematical sign, that I didn't understand.

They say (Inverse of DFT Matrix) F^-1 * c = v

[image: F^-1]

And then, there is an equality that I didn't get: [image]

What does the bar on top of Fn mean? I know for example for the Discrete Cosine Transform DCT, Cn^-1 = Cn^T (Transpose). But for the DFT I don't get the bar on top of Fn.

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: It is the conjugation operation. $\omega^k$ are complex umbers.

Comment: The bar on top denotes the complex  conjugation.